# Weird Unity Sprite Boarder

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Sorry I can't post images yet. But my problem is that the sprites that I have put my game scene have a weird box around them. It's like a transparent black background that they all have

The effect is not in the original png file. It appears in the scene and game view. I have no idea what's up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you upload an image to some host, say imgur.com, and post the link here?

Comment: Do you use SpriteRenderer component, and how is it set up?